# Obtaining component title from the Tridion broker

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, broker

This code works to get content from the broker for all components whos name begins with "MC":

```
    Criteria c1 = new ItemTitleCriteria("MC%",  Criteria.Like);

    //Create query
    Query myQuery = new Query(c1);

    String[] itemURIs = myQuery.ExecuteQuery();
    ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler();
    foreach (string componentUri in itemURIs)
    {
        String content = cpAssembler.GetContent(componentUri, componentTemplateUri);
    }
```

However, I am struggling to find in the api where I can actually access the names (or titles) of each component returned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `ComponentMetaFactory` class to interrogate the metadata of your component.

```
Criteria c1 = new ItemTitleCriteria("MC%", Criteria.Like);

//Create query
Query myQuery = new Query(c1);

String[] itemURIs = myQuery.ExecuteQuery();
ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler();
ComponentMetaFactory cmFactory = new ComponentMetaFactory(publicationId);

foreach (string componentUri in itemURIs)
{
    String content = cpAssembler.GetContent(componentUri, componentTemplateUri);
    IComponentMeta componentMeta = cmFactory.GetMeta(componentUri);
    string componentTitle = componentMeta.Title;
}
```